# How to change the path structure from built Vue project?

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, babeljs

So I have a Vue project created with the handy vue ui command.
package.json has the build script to compile the project in the dist folder.

An issue I'm facing is that the index.html file references to js and css files this way:

```
<link href="/js/app.66f30e0a.js" rel="preload" as="script">
<link href="/js/chunk-vendors.410e1ec5.js" rel="preload" as="script">
<link href="/css/app.20c14d91.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/chunk-vendors.410e1ec5.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.66f30e0a.js"></script>
```

But I need it to do it this way because of the software I'm putting these files on:

```
<link href="./js/app.66f30e0a.js" rel="preload" as="script">
<link href="./js/chunk-vendors.410e1ec5.js" rel="preload" as="script">
<link href="./css/app.20c14d91.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="./js/chunk-vendors.410e1ec5.js"></script>
<script src="./js/app.66f30e0a.js"></script>
```

So basically adding the period character before the path.

I know this can be changed somehow using webpack, but this is using babel and I'm a total novice in terms of project config.
This is the babel.config.js file right now:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

What would I need to add/change in order to get the path structure I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Babel isn’t the bundler using the build your project. If you’re using Vue CLI you’re still using webpack. What you want is to change the `publicPath` so it points to `./` or whatever absolute custom path you have: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

Comment: @Terry I can't find any vue.config.js file, this is my project structure: https://gyazo.com/eda6f0b99f2849272d1ebedb9fdd3a1a
There's no vue field in my package.json file either

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `vue.config.js` file into your project root, and inside something like:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: './'
}
```

For further reading, see the [Vue cli docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js).

Comment: I created the file with this code and built the project, same result with the paths https://i.gyazo.com/77903578ce4b98042574f1fa034e83ba.png

Comment: alright, I had to do the stupidest thing ever and Idk why 
`publicPath: '' + './' + './'` It worked with this